# Differential equation evaluated at a point

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having tremendous troubles getting the solution for a differential equation that should be satisfied when the argument of the function is `(u-t)`, it is important that it is at `(u-t)`, since the equation has other functions of `t` that should affect the solution if say I use another variable. No matter what I do I get the error that `(u-t)` can't be used as a variable and I don't know how to get around this. Any help in this area would be highly appreciated it! (Note: I can find a solution for using `t` as a variable but when replacing by `(u-t)` the function found with just `t` as a variable is no longer a solution)

```
γA[t_] := γA[t] = σD^2/  (t + σD^2/ΓA);
γB[t_] := γB[t] = σD^2/ (t + σD^2/ΓB);
FC[t_] := FC[t] = - 2 H[u - t] (γB[t]/σD^2 - (x (γB[t] - γA[t]) )/σD^2) + ( (
 x (x - 1))/(2 σD^2)) + 2 H[u - t]^2 ((γB[t] - γA[t])^2/σD^2) +  D[H[u - t], t];
sol = DSolve[FC[t] == 0, H[u - t], u - t]
```

Comment: Rather than images, post your code in code blocks so that it can be copied and pasted into a Mma notebook.

Comment: Can you use the substitution `g[t] == H[u-t]` (and `-g'[t] == H'[u-t]`)?

Comment: No, the substitution doesn't work because the other two functions, gammaA and gammaB also depend on time, and are in the equation to be satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is inelegant but effective,

```
FC[t] // Simplify
Simplify[% /. t -> u - tt
(* ((-1 + x) x)/(2 σD^2) - (2 ((-tt + u) ΓA ΓB + (x (ΓA - ΓB) + ΓB) σD^2) H[tt])/
   ((-tt ΓA + u ΓA + σD^2) (-tt ΓB + u ΓB + σD^2)) + (2 (ΓA - ΓB)^2 σD^6 H[tt]^2)
   /((-tt ΓA + u ΓA + σD^2)^2 (-tt ΓB + u ΓB + σD^2)^2) - Derivative[1][H][tt] *)

Simplify[Flatten@DSolve[% == 0, H[tt], tt] /. tt -> u - t]
(* {H[-t + u] -> (1/(2 (ΓA - ΓB)^2 σD^6 (t - u + C[1])))(t ΓA + σD^2) (t ΓB + σD^2) 
    (σD^2 (u (ΓA - x ΓA + x ΓB) + σD^2 + ((-1 + x) ΓA - x ΓB) C[1]) + 
    t (u ΓA ΓB + x (ΓA - ΓB) σD^2 + ΓB (σD^2 - ΓA C[1])))} *)
```

Comment: Thank you bbgodfrey! Unfortunatly the solution that comes by using this method wouldn't satisfy `Simplify[  -2 HC[
    u - t] (\[Gamma]B[t]/\[Sigma]D^2 - ( 
     x (\[Gamma]B[t] - \[Gamma]A[t]) )/\[Sigma]D^2) + ( (x (x - 1))/(
   2 \[Sigma]D^2)) + 
  2 HC[u - t]^2 ((\[Gamma]B[t] - \[Gamma]A[t])^2/\[Sigma]D^2) +  
  D[HC[u - t], t]]` 
Which is what should be equal to zero as a result.

Comment: @user3501293  I may have had a sign error.  Try it now.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! It does work just fine :D :D :D